# How to check if a cell value is within 7 days from today

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, date

I have a column in my `GridView` which displays date from a SQL query in this format: `mm-dd-yyyy` and I want to change the font color if the cell value is within 7 days from today's date.

This is what I have but it make everything the same color:

```
int inDateOffset = 7; //within 7 days makes it a risk item...
if (DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text).Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-inDateOffset).Date)
{
    e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = Color.FromName("#DCA704");
    e.Row.Cells[3].ToolTip = "Task is at Risk";
}
```

How do I modify the code so anything within 7 days from today will be in the color, `#DCA704`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check is checking if the date is greater than 7 days *ago*. Flip it around so that your check is whether the date is less than 7 days from now:

```
if (DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text).Date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(inDateOffset).Date)
```

Comment: This will let me know if something is within 7 days from today?

Comment: How do I check in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if` statement to check the resulting `TimeSpan`, and add 7 Days:

```
if ((DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text).Date 
     - DateTime.Now.AddDays(inDateOffset).Date).TotalDays <= 7)
```